# Ethanol for wood polishing

Tags: everyday-chemistry

We use ordinary spirit to polish wood, and it contains ethanol. What makes ethanol a good polishing agent for wood? What effect does it causes on wood so that it shines?

Comment: Spirit polish, as it is termed, has shellac dissolved in the ethanol. Could you post a picture of the product you use? I suspect there is more going on here.

Answer (score 1):

Ethanol is an organic solvent. I would **guess** that it makes wood shine by:

1. Cleaning the surface, dissolving away organic compounds
2. Maybe slightly dissolving (?) a thin layer of [cellulose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellulose) at the surface of the wood, removing irregularities and making it more malleable, hence easier to polish

There may be more specific interactions between wood and ethanol, but I don't know about them.